# I wanna perform back & forth functionality animation, I've used odd & even click counts but it stops after 1st cycle

Tags: java, android

```
//Initializing clickCount
int clickCount = 0;  
public void animateButton(View view) {

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            clickCount++;
            if(clickCount%2==0 && clickCount==0){  //clickCount=0 declared in global variable
          button.animate().translationX(400);
            }
            else {
                button.animate().translationX(-400);
            }
        }
    });
```

Or you can suggest any other method too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your if statement is true only once, at initialization. Afterwards clickCount is 1,2,3,... which is `clickCount==0 : False` so the if statement is also false.

Comment: So should I go for loops?

Comment: No, it should work if you simply remove 'clickCount==0' so that your if statement is ' if(clickCount%2==0)'...